# SQL help to remove an imported text error

Tags: ee3, query, sql

We recently migrated a site, and any line break imported as /n. This was not a huge deal for the templates, but it is for the entries.

This is for an EE3 site, and I just don't write SQL code that much. Can I get some assistance writing a query that will replace `/n` with `<br />` in field_id_1 for all entries whose channel id is 2?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found the "Data Search and Replace" utility from within EE3. That works perfectly!